# Convergence of $\mathbb{E}|\int X(\omega,x) (m_k(dx)-m(dx))|^2$ when $m_k(x)dx$ tends to $mdx$ in Wasserstein 2 distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we suppose that $m_k$, $m$ are probability densities with finite second moment such that $m_k(x)dx$ tends to $mdx$ in Wasserstein 2 distance as $k \to \infty$. If $X(\omega,x)$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}(|X(\omega,x)|^2) <1$ for any $x$, can I conclude that $\mathbb{E}|\int X(\omega,x) (m_k(x)dx-m(x)dx)|^2$ tends to $0$ as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: I doubt this true, without further assumptions on $X$, regarding the spacial variable.

Comment: I have added the condition of finite second moment, do you think it is possible?

Comment: Take a Dirac sequence as example: then why should $\mathbb{E}|X(\omega,1/k)-X(\omega,0)|^{2}$ converge to zero? I see no reason. I would expect you'll need e.g. some continuity assumption with respect to $x$, in which case your result will follow, because Wasserstein convergence implies weak convergence of measures.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. If I have the pointwise continuity with respect to $x$ under the $L^2$, how does the proof look like?